# Receive notification in ASP.net if table from SQL was Updated/Changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get notification in my ASP.net Website from database if a table was been modified?

**Example:** if  there is new message that come to my account. It will notify me on my website. I've tried to use ajax on this kind of feature but I want a better solution on this. AJAX is keep on requesting/communicating on the server even there is not new update on my table that why I find it not that good.

Please Help me on this problem.

What technology I should use? or please give me some related article.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get notification to your ASP.NET Website without an ajax request which keeps on communicating to a server in a given time interval. You can use SQL triggers to get information that your table has been updated or row has been added/deleted but to get that information too you'll need to make a request to your database server. I haven't came across any architecture in which database server automatically communicates to your web application/website until and unless a request is made by web application/website.

Comment: oh I see. I thought there is a solution/way to do that. Anyway thanks for your responds Sid M.

Comment: I also tried to do the same some time ago but came out with this conclusion. Hope i answered your question?

Comment: I also preferred to use signalR but the problem is my project was developed in .net2.0, so still I cannot but only JQuery.

Comment: signalR is good... can you mark it as answer, if you got answer to your question?

Comment: On this page (stack overflow), what do think what technology is they've used to build this page?

Comment: It would be very hard for me to comment on this as I'm also not sure, there are many technologies about which i personally haven't heard about.. so i can't comment on it. However if you are curious to know you can ask the same question on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ . You might get more accurate information over there.

Comment: okay. can you advise me on some technology that you've used in order to achieve the thing that I wanna do?

Comment: In ASP.NET you have to do it by ajax request and response, if you want to know specifically that your table is updated or record is added/ deleted then you must create triggers and then make request on that trigger table to know what operation has been performed on your main table. :) Sry for late response.

Comment: but I think that trigger will not be able to notify me or not reflect the notification on the interface itself. only on the backend side. Am I right?

Comment: yeah you'll have to make a db request to the trigger table.

Comment: but the thing is I wanna do is the DB will notify me in my front end when it was been updated. rather the Table I mean.

Comment: the project that I'm doing is like a chat. which I don't want to use an AJAX request every interval.